# Entity Framework: difference between Detach and AsNoTracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My goal is to copy an existing Entity, slightly modify it, and insert the modified version.

I have tried two different methods that both appear to work:

```
var thing = context.Things.Where(x => x.SomeID == someid).AsNoTracking().Single();
thing.AnotherID = 1234;
context.Things.AddObject(thing);
context.SaveChanges();

var thing = context.Things.Where(x => x.SomeID == someid).Single();
context.Detach(thing);
thing.AnotherID = 1234;
context.Things.AddObject(thing);
context.SaveChanges();
```

From what I can tell they both are accomplishing my goal. Is one of these better than the other, or are they both equally fine (or wrong!?)

Comment: FYI, since you used `FirstOrDefault`, `thing` could be `null`. You need to check for `null` before trying to use `thing`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - thx. I edited it to use Single instead.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first version is better and I would prefer it because

- it expresses better that you don't want to track changes of the existing entity
- it doesn't attach the entity to the context in the first place while the second version attaches and then immediately detaches it (which most likely will also have slightly worse performance)
- it perserves relationships (doesn't matter in this simple example, but generally) while detaching an entity only detaches the entity itself that you pass into `Detach`. Related children will stay attached which comes with the price that the relationships will be cleared (a navigation collection of child entities for example would be emptied, a reference navigation property would be set to `null`) since EF does not allow object graphs with a mix of attached and detached entities.

Comment: Outstanding answer. Thanks.

Comment: If you only have 1 item, it'll only be slightly worse performance. But if you have thousands, then it's the difference between a 3 second operation vs a 15 minute operation. Yes, those are real figures ;-)