# NoTracking object in CodeFirst

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

We are migrating an asp.net application to `CodeFirst`(we used `.net 3.5` and `EF`). In our code, we had:

```
this.myObjectContext.myTable.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking
```

I want to achieve the same thing using `CodeFirst`. If I use

```
this.myObjectContext.myTable.AsNoTracking()
```

this returns a new query where the entities returned will not be cached in the `DbContext` or `ObjectContext`, but this means that everywhere I want to use this table in my page with `NoTracking`, I will have to add `AsNoTracking()` , while when setting the merge option, I had to do this only once in my page.

Is there a way to achieve this using `.net 4.5.2`, `EF 6` and `CodeFirst`?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726878/global-setting-for-asnotracking

Comment: Yes, indeed, this answers my question. Thanks