# Issue with C# EF Core and Microsoft SQL Server database - cannot insert explicit value for identity column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm facing an issue while trying to add a new client to my database using EF Core and C#, where the client entity has a reference to a `WelfareOffice`. I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'WelfareOffices' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Here's a simplified version of my entity classes:

```
public class Client : AuditableEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public WelfareOffice WelfareOffice { get; set; }
}

public class WelfareOffice : AuditableEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName;
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to add a new `Client` to the database and set the `WelfareOffice` property to an instance that I've already retrieved from the database.

I'm not explicitly setting the `Id` of the `WelfareOffice`, but it seems like EF Core is trying to insert it as an identity value.

- I'm using EFCORE 7x...
- I'm not using "AsNoTracking"

```
private ClientDto _clientToAdd = new()
{
    Id = 0,
    FirstName = string.Empty,
    LastName = string.Empty,
    Birthday = default,
    Street = string.Empty,
    ZipCode = string.Empty,
    City = string.Empty,
    PhoneNumber = string.Empty,
    Email = string.Empty,
    TypeOfAid = string.Empty,
    WelfareOffice = null,
    SpecializedServiceHours = SpecializedServiceHours.Periodic,
    ApprovalPeriodFrom = default,
    ApprovalPeriodUntil = default,
    ResponsibleYouthWelfareOffice = string.Empty,
    TypeOfAppointment = string.Empty,
    Number = string.Empty,
    HoursOfSpecialistServicesInPeriod = 0,
    MonthsPerPeriod = 0
};
    
allWelfareOffices = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<WelfareOfficeDto>>("api/welfareoffice/getallwelfareoffices");

_welfareOffices = _allWelfareOffices;
    
_clientToAdd.WelfareOffice = _welfareOffices.First(x => x.Id == _selectedWelfareOfficeId);
```

Here  is the whole error:

```
---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'WelFareOffices' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Clients' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__209_0(Task`1 result)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

Any help or insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the code where you are trying to do the insert?

Comment: Why are you using EFCore 2.2? That's dreadfully out-of-date and has numerous bugs and missing features - if you update to EF Core 7+ I'm confident it'll just-work.

Comment: *"an instance that I've already retrieved from the database."* - did you use [`.AsNoTracking`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12211749) somewhere? EF might think the object is a new entry and use `insert` instead of `update`.

Comment: @NorSer
See update

Comment: @BagusTesa
See  update

Comment: @Dai
See update

Comment: @CCTB have you checked anything in the config that may cause similar behaviour to `.AsNoTracking()`, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39809419)?

Comment: @CCTB I noticed you're using fields, not locals, to store temporary EF entity objects - that probably has something to do with it.

Comment: @BagusTesa
I only have this:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connection,
        options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()));

Comment: @Dai
Same error here:
https://pastebin.com/nv1TTPpe

Comment: The Reason was, that my ID was set by myself it needs to be null.